# Embed two blocks in a block

Tags: blocks, theming

I have three blocks A, B and C and I need to embed the blocks A and B into the template of a block C.  Is it possible?

Comment: I am just curious, why would you do this? So that you could move two other block around seamlessly by using one block as a container, or 'basket'?

Comment: My idea is that two blocks are in the same space that one block in the right column.  I thought in blocks embed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, when you create a block programatically you can add any content inclusive another blocks.

In your block function you can do something like:

```
$blockA = module_invoke('block', 'block_view', 1);
$blockB = module_invoke('block', 'block_view', 2);
return $blockA['content'].$blockB['content'];
```

Comment: hello Gnuget - many thx for the great answer. This is convincing me. I love your solution! Greetings

Answer (score 3):

Alternately, create a View that contains A, B, and C in some combination, and expose it as a block.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can embed several blocks within another mini-panel block, with the Panels module.